# From inside a docker, activate Python virtual env residing on host

Tags: python, docker, virtualenv

I set up a containerized JupyterHub server, that spawns containerized JupyterLab notebook servers, one per user. The latter container mounts the user's host home dir, so that the user can access his scripts and notebooks from the JupterLab container.

However, the user may not be satisfied with the Python environment bundled with the JupyterLab docker, and may want to add a Jupyter kernel from a custom virtual env. And, instead of recreating a virtual env inside the container, the user is likely to prefer reusing some virtual env he already created on the host machine, in his home folder.

So, I tried to activate a virtual env created on the host machine, from Jupyterlab container, with something like:

`source /path/to/env/bin/activate`

`which python` then points to the correct Python interpreter, that is, `/path/to/env/bin/python`

Unfortunately when I then try executing Python (from Jupyerlab docker), it throws the following error:

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f48a97de080 (most recent call first):
Aborted
```

So, is it even possible to do this, that is, activate a virtual env created on host, from a container? In other word, to share virtual envs between host and container?

Comment: I guess your technical problem is that a virtual env usually contains symlinks to the "real" binaries and libraries. If these are located in a different place on the host than in the container, then resolution of these symlinks will fail.

Comment: If you're trying to use host users, host directories, and the host Python interpreter, it seems like an isolation system like Docker isn't really a good match for your setup.  Can you run the Jupyter server directly on the host instead?